# How can I magnify an Image in openCV without resize

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have an image with size 75x75 pixels and I want to select a Region of Interest in this image.
The small size of the image does not allow an accurate selection of the interesting pixels using opencv.

I already have a ROI selection function using the opencv library.

Is there a way to *magnify* each pixel so that opencv displays each image pixel using 4 pixels of the screen? Resizing is not an option since I need the exact pixel positions of the ROI.

Comment: what if you upscale (resize) the image by a factor of 4, select your ROI, and then downscale the ROI by the same factor 4?

Comment: Is [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) an option? I'm pretty sure, there are mouse click event handling routine to capture coordinates of mouse clicks or similar.